# Access public method defined on abstract base class from Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I'm attempting to use the DNSJava library from clojure. I attempt the following:

```
dmarced.dns> (def results (.run (Lookup. "google.com" Type/TXT)))
#'dmarced.dns/results
dmarced.dns> (def r (get results 0))
#'dmarced.dns/r
dmarced.dns> r
#object[org.xbill.DNS.TXTRecord 0x687a3556 "google.com.\t\t3599\tIN\tTXT\t\"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all\""]
dmarced.dns> (class r)
org.xbill.DNS.TXTRecord
dmarced.dns> (instance? TXTRecord r)
true
```

Great! I know from the [docs](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/dnsjava-current/doc/org/xbill/DNS/TXTRecord.html) that I should be able to use .getStrings to get the content of the record.

```
dmarced.dns> (.getStrings r)
Reflection warning, *cider-repl dmarced*:150:13 - reference to field getStrings can't be resolved.
IllegalArgumentException Can't call public method of non-public class: public java.util.List org.xbill.DNS.TXTBase.getStrings()  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:88)
```

Ok quick google tells me this can be solved via type hints:

```
dmarced.dns> (.getStrings ^TXTRecord r)
Reflection warning, *cider-repl dmarced*:153:13 - call to method getStrings on org.xbill.DNS.TXTRecord can't be resolved (argument types: ).
IllegalArgumentException Can't call public method of non-public class: public java.util.List org.xbill.DNS.TXTBase.getStrings()  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:88)
```

Huh. At I've search Google further, and read the full page on [interop](http://clojure.org/reference/java_interop), but I'm not having any luck.

Looking at the source for [TXTRecord](https://github.com/dnsjava/dnsjava/blob/master/org/xbill/DNS/TXTRecord.java) I see that it extends [TXTBase](https://github.com/dnsjava/dnsjava/blob/master/org/xbill/DNS/TXTBase.java) which is an abstract class where [getStrings](https://github.com/dnsjava/dnsjava/blob/master/org/xbill/DNS/TXTBase.java#L97) is implemented. Since TXTRecord extends it, I should have access to getStrings through that (and I went so far as to write a Java program to verify it.

Does anyone know how I can access this via Clojure?

**EDIT** Working java program

```
import org.xbill.DNS.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws TextParseException {
        Lookup l = new Lookup("google.com", Type.TXT);
        Record [] rs = l.run();
        for(int i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {
            TXTRecord tr = (TXTRecord)rs[i];
            for(int j = 0; j < tr.getStrings().size(); j ++) {
                System.out.println(tr.getStrings().get(j));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, `TXTBase` is not declared as `public`.  So I don't know why you'd have access to any methods declared on that class outside the `org.xbill.dns` package.  And that's exactly what the exception message hints at -- "Can't call public method on **non-public** class" (emphasis added).  Could you add the Java program that works so we can compare with the Clojure version, please?

Comment: Added. Both are using dnsjava 2.1.7 off maven. I can provide the gradle and project.clj files if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks that it is a known bug [CLJ-1243](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1243). You can find more details and probably root cause by reading [Netty issue description](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1780):

> The public methods inherited from AbstractBootstrap cannot be invoked
>   via the Java reflection API due to long-standing bugs such as
>   JDK-4283544.
>
> This is a serious problem for alternative JVM languages which use
>   reflection to discover Java methods. For example, Clojure uses
>   reflection in its compiler, and it cannot invoke these methods at all,
>   as reported in CLJ-1243.

And part of the description from the [JDK bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4283544):

> java.lang.reflect.Field (get* and set*) and Method (invoke) base their
>   access check on the declaring class.  This is contrary to the JLS,
>   which defines accessibility in terms of the reference type.

Answer (score 1):

Piotrek seems to be right about why it's occurring. The Clojure bug report suggests writing a Java class to get the information. It's not pretty but I managed to work around it with

```
dmarced.core> (def txt-strings-method (doto (.getDeclaredMethod TXTBase "getStrings" nil) (.setAccessible true)))
#'dmarced.core/txt-strings-method
dmarced.core> (defn get-txt-strings [r]
                (.invoke m r nil))
#'dmarced.core/get-txt-strings
dmarced.core> (get-txt-strings r)
["v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"]
dmarced.core>
```